# Discord.py embed message command

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code... it isn't working

```
@client.command(aliases=['em', 'embedm', 'e'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(ctx, *, m_title, m_description, m_color):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Title {m_title}",description=f"Descrip {m_description}",color={m_color})

    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

I tried a couple other ways but none of them worked...

Comment: title = f"Title {m_title}"  (You need the f before the start of the string) AND
color = m_color  (It's not in an f-string, so it doesn't need the { } )

Answer (score 0):

To add varibles in a string you should do it like that: `f"Hi {variable}"`.
And the embed color code should be like that:

```
color = m_color
```

**So your revised code is:**

```
@client.command(aliases=['em', 'embedm', 'e'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(ctx, *, m_title, m_description, m_color):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"Title {m_title}",description=f"Descrip {m_description}",color=m_color)

    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```